# How do I set the conditional requirements and how do I make an option one-time

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, for room_attic, how can I let option A show different things when you have a different condition, like, when you have cheese you can throw in it when you have a ball of string, you can use it, and then come back two different results. And how to make an option one time, like after you pick up the ball of string, and when you go back to def_living room, it will not show again string information.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

def Living_room():
    print("\nLiving room contents: a pot of soil, stairs going up, a dark entranceway, a ball of a string")
    print("A).Viewing the pot of soil") 
    print("B). Stairs going up")
    print("C). Dark entranceway")
    print("D). Pick Ball of string")
    choice = input("");
    if "A" in choice:
        (""" it looks dry""")
    elif "B" in choice:
        room_attic()
    elif "C" in choice:
        room_bedroom()
    else "D" in choice:
        print("picked up")
def room_attic():
    print("\nLiving room contents: a pot of soil, stairs going up, a dark entranceway, a ball of a string")
    print("A). A hole") 
    print("B). Chess on the ground")
    print("C). Stairs going down")
    choice = input("");
    if "A" in choice:
        print("you can use the Ball of string")
    elif "B" in choice:
        print("you picked up the chess")
    elif "C" in choice:
        Living_room()
```

Comment: Sry for that, changed already, do you have any idea for the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of coding all the prompts you want to print inside the function, you could save them to a list or dictionary. Then, when a prompt is no longer available to use, you could `del` it from the list/dictionary.

For example, each element of `living_room_prompts` is a tuple containing four elements: the prompt string, the function to call if that prompt is selected, and the arguments to pass to the callback function, and a boolean telling us whether or not we can select this option again:

```
living_room_prompts = [
    ("Viewing the pot of soil", print, ["it looks dry"], True),
    ("Stairs going up", room_attic, [], True),
    ("Dark entranceway", room_bedroom, [], True),
    ("Pick ball of string", print, ["Picked up"], False)
]
```

Let's define a function that will print all these prompts, ask for the user's choice, and return that choice:

```
def ask_user(prompts):
    for number, item in enumerate(prompts):
        question = f"{number+1}) {item[0]}" # list indices are zero based, so add 1 to the index
        print(question)
    choice = int(input("> ")) # Convert user's choice to an integer
    return choice - 1 # Python list indices are zero based, so subtract 1 from user's choice to get index
```

Next, in our `living_room()` function, we

- Ask for the user's choice
- Delete the item if it's not repeatable
- Call the `callback` function giving it `callback_args` using [argument unpacking](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/)
  :

```
def living_room():
    print("\nLiving room: ")
    choice = ask_user(living_room_prompts)
    user_choice_item =  living_room_prompts[choice] 

    # Unpack the tuple
    prompt, callback, callback_args, is_repeatable = user_choice_item
    if not is_repeatable:
        # If you can't select this option again, delete it from the list
        del living_room_prompts[choice]

    # Call the function you need to call with its arguments:
    callback(*callback_args)
```

To see how this works, let's define a single action in the attic and bedroom: go back to the living room.

```
attic_prompts = [
    ("Go back to living room", living_room, [], True)
]

bedroom_prompts = [
    ("Go back to living room", living_room, [], True)
]

def room_attic():
    print("\nAttic:")
    choice = ask_user(attic_prompts)
    user_choice_item = attic_prompts[choice]
    prompt, callback, callback_args, is_repeatable = user_choice_item
    callback(*callback_args)

def room_bedroom():
    print("\nBedroom:")
    choice = ask_user(bedroom_prompts)
    user_choice_item = bedroom_prompts[choice]
    prompt, callback, callback_args, is_repeatable = user_choice_item
    callback(*callback_args)
```

Now let's run this:

```
while True:
    living_room()
```

And we get the following output:

```
Living room: 
1) Viewing the pot of soil
2) Stairs going up
3) Dark entranceway
4) Pick ball of string

> 4
Picked up

Living room: 
1) Viewing the pot of soil
2) Stairs going up
3) Dark entranceway

> 2

Attic: 
1) Go back to living room

> 1

Living room: 
1) Viewing the pot of soil
2) Stairs going up
3) Dark entranceway
```